# How to target first child of selector when testing component with jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to write a test to to target if a default prop is passed in the HTML correctly using `jest` and `vue-test-utils`. I can not seem to find my target selector. I want to be able to test that a particular `p` tag contains the proper text. In this case if a name prop is passed, it renders that. If not, then the default function renders the default `payTo` value.

I've been trying several combinations of chaining to the wrapper to no avail.

```
console.log(wrapper.html()) // presents all the page html
```

```
console.log(wrapper.classes()) // array showing only one class ('.row-space-between')
```

Here is my component:

```
<template>
  <div class="row-space-between">
    <div>
      <h3>{{ $t('label.payTo') }}</h3>
      <p>{{ merchantName.payTo }}</p> // TARGET SELECTOR
    </div>
    <div class="align-right">
      <h3>{{ $t('label.estimatedTotal') }}</h3>
      <p>{{ amount }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'PayTo',
  props: {
    'merchant-name': {
      type: Object,
      // default: {} with type obj or arr default function is required
      default: function () {
        return { merchantName: {
          payTo: 'Order Total'
         }
       }
    },
    amount: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my test:

```
describe('PayTo.vue', () => {
  let wrapper

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(PayTo, {
      mocks: {
        $t
      },
      propsData: {
        merchantName: {
          payTo: 'foo-merchant-name'
        },
        amount: '$110.00'
      }
    })
  })
  it('[positive] should render correct contents', () => {
    // PayTo.props.merchantName.default()
    expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot()
  })

  // The following two tests satisfy testing the default function in PayTo.vue props validation if not tested, coverage falls to zero

  // This test is meaningless until I can be more specific in targeting

  it('[positive] should display `AWS`', () => {
    wrapper.setProps({
      merchantName: {
        payTo: 'AWS'
      }
    })
    expect(wrapper.contains('p'))
  })

  it('[negative] should display `Order Total`', () => {
    wrapper.setProps({
      merchantName: {
        payTo: 'Order Total'
      }
    })
    console.log(wrapper.contains('div > p'))
    expect(wrapper.contains('p'))
  })
```

Comment: css :first-child?

Comment: I tried `expect(wrapper.contains(div:first-child > p))`. Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) pseudo-class could be used here:

```
expect(wrapper.contains("div:first-child > p")).toBeTruthy()
```

I would also verify the text in `p` matches the expected value:

```
expect(wrapper.find("div:first-child > p").text()).toBe("Order Total")
```

Also note your `merchant-name` prop's default value should not contain another `merchantName` key. Otherwise, when that prop is not specified, `payTo` would be accessed by `merchantName.merchantName.payTo`.

```
props: {
  "merchant-name": {
    type: Object,
    default: function() {
      return {
        // merchantName: {  // DON'T DO THIS
        //  payTo: "Order Total"
        // }

        payTo: "Order Total"
      }
    }
  },
}
```

[image: Edit Selectors in @vue/test-utils]